# Haskell: error: parse error on input ‘,’

Tags: haskell

```
type Vertex = (Float, Float)

distance :: Vertex -> Vertex -> Float
distance (x, y) (x`, y`)
   = (sqrt ((x^2 - x`^2) + (y^2 - y`^2)))
```

hey for distance between two vertices, I get the error "error: parse error on input ‘,’"

Sorry very basic :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using backticks, `, rather than single quotes, '. Backticks allow you to use an identifier in an infix position, e.g.,

```
x `elem` xs
```

while single quotes are a valid character in an identifier, e.g.,

```
(x', y')
```

Note that they are also used for character literals, e.g., `'a'`, so you can't begin an identifier with a single quote.

Comment: oh ofcourse haha. Upon making the change to ', it returns NaN when I try to use the function. Do you have any idea what's causing that?

Comment: @Matt You are calling sqrt with negative arguments (your formula is wrong).